# histones in the Hershey / Chase experiment

Tags: proteins

When DNA is injected into the cell why aren't histones(protein) also injected and why wouldn't the radioactive sulfur therefore also be present in the infected cell

Comment: Bacteria do not have histones - the DNA is just naked in the cytoplasm. Therefore no protein was transferred.

Comment: @MattDMo The DNA injected onto the bacteria was T2 bacteriophage DNA.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that eukaryotic chromosomes have histones associated with them. But the DNA in the Hershey-Chase experiment was viral, no histones.